# Print object items inside *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print object items dynamically

```
const data = {
    title1: {
      name: "real title",
      value: ""
    },
    title2: {
      name: "real title2",
      value: ""
    },
    title3: {
      name: "real title3",
      value: ""
    },
    title4: {
      name: "real title4",
      value: ""
    },
    title5: {
      name: "real title5",
      value: ""
    },
    title6: {
      name: "real title6",
      value: ""
    }
};
```

I would print a list of `data.title[i].name`.

First I get titles list in array so that I could loop on them.

```
const titlesList = Object.keys(this.data);
```

then in HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let title of titlesList">
   {{ data.title.name }}
</div>
```

What I would print like:

```
 - real title 
 - real title1
 - real title2
 - ...
```

The error that I get:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Use {{title.name}} instead of {{data.title.name}}

Comment: It's empty because title contains only an array of data keys so: title1; title2, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access via `[]` notation because your property key is stored in the `title` range variable. `[]` will evaluate the expression inside it, get the value and try to find property with that value.

```
<div *ngFor="let title of titlesList">
   {{ data[title].name }}
</div>
```

Or instead of `Object.keys` you can use `Object.values (ES8)`

```
titlesList = Object.values(this.data);
```

and in the markup

```
 <div *ngFor="let title of titlesList">
    {{ title.name }}
 </div>
```

*Angular 6.1* provides a new **[KeyValue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)** pipe. Using this you can just use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data| keyvalue">
   {{ item.key }} - {{ item.value.name }} 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you used `data[title].name` ?

Comment: right ! I was testing with `data.[title].name` ( with a dot after data ) Thanks that's working

Comment: @ThierryV - The variable `title` will take the values "title1", "title2", etc.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest relase of Angular 6.1 you can do it with the keyvalue pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data| keyvalue">
   {{item.value.name}} 
</div>
```